# Como Imprimir valores aleatorios?

Tags: array, c, bucle-for, arraylist, random

Realiza un programa que genere de manera aleatoria 80 números en el intervalo del conjunto del 1 al 100, que no
se repitan, y después genera una lista con los 20 números que hagan falta.

Estoy tratando de hacer un array de 100 numeros, para evaluarlos a 0. Despues con un For poner 80 de esos 100 numeros = 1. Por ende quedaria 80-- 1 y 20-- 0 . No me sale, alguien me podria ayudar por favor?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int miArray[100], i;

    for ( i=0; i<100; i++) {
        miArray[i]=0;
    }

    printf("\n Los valores aleatorios son:");

    for ( i=0; i<100; i++) {
        printf("%d", miArray[i]);
    }

    int j, aleatorio ;
    srand(time(0));

    for (j=0; j<80; j++){
        aleatorio = 1+ rand() %(100);
        miArray[aleatorio] = 1;  
        printf("\n %d", miArray[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de la salida esperada?

Answer (score 0):

Hola no se si entendí bien pero si buscas que de 80 elementos de tu array de manera aleatoria tengan el valor de 1 entonces podrías intentar hacerlo de esta manera:

```
int j = 0, aleatorio ;
srand(time(0));

while(j < 80){
    aleatorio = 1+ rand() %(100);
    if(miArray[aleatorio] == 1){
        continue;
    }
    j++;
    miArray[aleatorio] = 1;
}

for ( i=0; i<100; i++) {
    printf("\n%d", miArray[i]);
}
```

Lo que hace es que si comprobar si la variable miArray[aleatorio] ya tiene el valor 1, lo que significa que previamente ya ingreso a ese índice entonces con continue lo que hace es seguir el loop sin sumar +1 a j.

Si es obligatorio usar un for tambien puede hacerse de esta forma:

```
for(j = 0; j < 80; j++){
    aleatorio = 1+ rand() %(100);
    if(miArray[aleatorio] == 1){
        j--;
        continue;
    }
    
    miArray[aleatorio] = 1;
}
```